# "Use of unassigned variable" in C# application

Tags: c#

SO, I have double checked this code about 10 times, and can not see why it gives me an unassigned variable error.

My method:

```
         private void Calculate(TextBox opOne, TextBox opTwo, TextBox txt_operation)
     {
         decimal operandOne = Convert.ToDecimal(opOne.Text);
         decimal operandTwo = Convert.ToDecimal(opTwo.Text);
         string operation = txt_operation.Text;
         decimal result;

         //determine and perform mathematical operation
         if (operation == "+")
             result = operandOne + operandTwo;
         else if (operation == "-")
             result = operandOne - operandTwo;
         else if (operation == "/")
             result = operandOne / operandTwo;
         else if (operation == "*")
             result = operandOne * operandTwo;

         string formattedResult = result.ToString("F4"); //this line has the error for the result variable, but the result variable is listed in the above if/else clauses

         //set formatted result text to text box
         txt_Result.Text = formattedResult;

     }
```

The error is on the line where I commented

SOLUTION:

this method is called after the data is checked for validity by another method. As a result, if we got to this point, the operation value IS one of the 4 choices, *, /, +, or -

So, simply, I changed the last 'else if()' statement to an else statement, because it is the only remaining possibility. No thing else is possible at that point.

```
             //determine and perform mathematical operation
         if (operation == "+")
             result = operandOne + operandTwo;
         else if (operation == "-")
             result = operandOne - operandTwo;
         else if (operation == "/")
             result = operandOne / operandTwo;
         else 
             result = operandOne * operandTwo;

         string formattedResult = result.ToString("F4");
```

Comment: BTW, C# lets you use strings with `switch`.

Comment: Try putting an `else { Response.Write("No if statement hit"); }` and if you see that line, then there is either something wrong with your if statements or your parameters/variable assignment

Answer (score 3):

If all `if`s fail (`operation` is none of `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`), `result` stays uninitialized.

Try something like:

```
if (operation == "+")
    result = operandOne + operandTwo;
else if (operation == "-")
    result = operandOne - operandTwo;
else if (operation == "/")
    result = operandOne / operandTwo;
else if (operation == "*")
    result = operandOne * operandTwo;
else
    throw new Exception("Unexpected operation.");

string formattedResult = result.ToString("F4");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me with how I solved it, which I will show in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize **result** with **0** for example or add **else** statement after all **else if** and assign some value to **result** inside it.

Comment: Your solution will work, but it will handle multiply operation whatever you type in except `+`, `-`, `/`, so the solution of AlexD  is better.